# What happened to old Firebase Analytics events report?

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-console

After recent Firebase Console update can not find the report for select_content event by content type and then for selected content type by item_id. I used these reports for study my Apps behaviour by log them with:

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
  AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\(title!)",
  AnalyticsParameterItemName: title!,
  AnalyticsParameterContentType: "cont",
])
```

for iOS

or with:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

for Android.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/11/updated-google-analytics-dashboard.html and https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/11091821?

Comment: Do you mean that you can get report for some type of select_content event by item_id? Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem but figured out a way to see some of the data again (without having to link my Firebase project to BigQuery):

1. You need to add *item_id* as a custom parameter definition (Firebase/Analytics/Custom Definitions).  Set scope to *Event* and Event Parameter to *item_id*.  You can make dimension name whatever you want, but I just called it *item_id*.  It could take a day for this change to propagate.
2. You need to have a Google Analytics account.  I already had one because that's what I was using before Google made mobile analytics users switch to Firebase.  I'm pretty sure you can still create Google Analytics accounts for free.
3. Link your Firebase project to google analytics by going to your Firebase project settings (gear icon next to project overview in the upper-left), selecting integrations, and then link to Google Analytics.
4. In your linked Google Analytics project, you can use the explore function (on the left below reports) to do more advanced queries on the data.
5. Create a new blank exploration.
6. Add *Content type* and *item_id* to the available dimensions (hit the plus next to the *Dimensions* on the left.)
7. Add *Event count* to metrics on the left.
8. Drag both *Content type* and *item_id* to the *Rows* cell (below Segment Comparisons in the Tab Settings).
9. Select *Yes* for Nested Rows.
10. Drag *Event count* to the Values cell.

I've found that these are mostly sampled events (i.e. the results are just a sampling of the full data) if the dataset is large, but it's better than nothing!

Oh also, in Google Analytics settings (gear icon in the lower left), select Data Settings / Data Retention, and choose 14 months so you'll be able to query more data going forward.  At least I hope this will work.  I noticed I could only query 2 months of data so I just changed the setting.

---

Here are some screenshots of my setup...

**Firebase custom parameter definitions** ("String" is my own parameter that I use for some events.)

[image: Custom parameter definitions]

---

**Select Content report in Google Analytics Explorer**

[image: Select content report in Google Analytics Explorer]

---

**Old select_content report in Firebase analytics.**  The item_id should show up as a custom parameter once you've added the custom definition, though it won't be correlated to the content_type.

[image: Old select_content report in Firebase analytics]

Comment: Interesting and super complicated :D In `Google Analytics` I have `(not set)` in `item_id` column when I set `item_id` to the `rows` under `Tab settings`.

Comment: I think the report will say "(not set)" as one of the entries when it's sampling the data (which you can tell from the red exclamation point in the upper right corner).  Are you seeing item_id in the old firebase analytics select_content report now?  (I'll post some pictures to clarify my setup and the results I'm seeing.)

Comment: Ah... also according to [the documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en): 'You will see a value of "not set" for a custom dimension during the first 48 hours.'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar setup and now I can see the `item_id` event in Google Analytics using the `Content ID` dimension in the Free-form report.

[image]