# Logging events via Firebase with GA4 in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

In this manual [Get started with Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android#start_logging_events) there is a section "Start logging events":

Java code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Kotlin code:

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_ITEM) {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image")
}
```

Questions:

1. Confusing between `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT` in Java the code and `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_ITEM` in the Kotlin code.. The both parameters are different (`SELECT_CONTENT` vs `SELECT_ITEM`). Webpage about events: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events is `Service Unavailable`.
2. When I go to the: Firebase -> Analytics -> Events -> select_content: there is: Events in last 30 minutes. I cannot list of all events. I don't see the values of selected event.. I don't see all the `select_content` events includes values.

I tried to create custom dimension in Custom definitions, I waited 24 hours and I still don't know where to see the event.

**Do you know, how to show all Events with values reported by `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT` ?** Like in old Firebase before update? This is image of the old Firebase `select_content`:
[image: select_content]

The new Firebase logging events is not clear at all to me.

[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69919833/4244605) with unaswered good question:

> Do you mean that you can get report for some type of select_content event by item_id? Did you try this?